# Connection Pooling in typeorm with postgressql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I've gone through enough articles and typeorm official documentation on setting up connection pooling with typeorm and postgressql but couldn't find a solution.

All the articles, I've seen so far explains about adding the max/Poolsize attribute in orm configuration or connection pooling but this is not setting up a pool of idle connections in the database.

When I verify pg_stat_activity table after the application bootstraps, I could not see any idle connections in the DB but when a request is sent to the application I could see an active connection to the DB

The max/poolSize attribute defined under the extras in the orm configuration merely acts as the max number of connections that can be opened from the application to the db concurrently.

What I'm expecting is that during the bootstrap, the application opens a predefined number of connections with the database and keep it in idle state. When a request comes into the application one of the idle connection is picked up and the request is served.

Can anyone provide your insights on how to have this configuration defined with typeorm and postgresql?

Comment: can you show some code. How you are trying to achieve this?

Comment: Did you dig any further into this? I too am a little confused as to how it could be pooling connections if it is just opening new connections when they are needed.

Answer (score 2):

TypeORM uses [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) which has built in pg-pool and doesn't have that kind of option, as far as I can tell.  It supports a max, and as your app needs more connections it will create them, so if you want to pre-warm it, or maybe load/stress test it, and see those additional connections you'll need to write some code that kicks off a bunch of async queries/inserts.

I think I understand what you're looking for as I used to do enterprise Java, and connection pools in things like [glassfish](http://--steadypoolsize%20%20%20%20%20%20The%20minimum%20and%20initial%20number%20of%20connections%20maintained%20in%20the%20pool.%20The%20default%20value%20is%208.) and jboss have more options where you can keep hot unused connections in the pool.  There are no such options in TypeORM/node-postgres though.

Comment: Thank you so much, My understanding is the same as you that typeorm/node-postgres doesn't have an option to warm up connections. I would like to reach out to wider audience and confirm this as the documentation was not very clear on this aspect

Comment: Try asking on their slack (link on the main typeorm page), but I think the answer would likely be you'd need to make a PR to node-postgres to add things to the pooling behavior.